# How do I use the Firebase AAR files in a Kotlin backend application with service account?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime Database that I want to use from a pure Kotlin backend application.

I've added the required gradle dependencies:

```
compile group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-core', version: '17.5.1'
compile group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-database', version: '19.6.0'
```

… and Google as a dependency repo:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

All these artifacts are resolved as Android `.aar` files. I don't think that in itself should be a problem for my Kotlin backend app, but apparently IntelliJ is unable to register them as a library root. This again means that I don't get any of the files on my classpath.

All the resources I can find on this tells me to use Android Studio, but that doesn't seem right from a backend Kotlin application.

Are AAR files only usable from Android applications? If so, what's the best way of creating a Kotlin service account application for Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I found the answer just after asking the question:

Most of the Firebase artifacts for Kotlin/Java are indeed for Android.

The correct SDK for service accounts is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin/7.1.0.